# Интернет-страницы в приложении для wp8

Tags: c#, xaml, браузер, windows-phone-8, winrt

Как добавить в приложение WinRT (C# и XAML) что-то на подобии браузера как я понял надо использовать webview, а как его использовать я не понял, напишите как использовать его, либо чем можно отображать интернет страницы в приложение для wp8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По запросу "windwos phone webview example" я нашёл в Гугле следующий <[пример](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7)>. Не вижу смысла копипастить сюда куски оттуда, лучше уж в оригинале смотреть. Всё ли понятно в примере, или есть ещё какие-нибудь вопросы?